# Issue with too many quotation marks for onclick attribute - jQuery, HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The following code doesn't work, but if I replace the `onclick` attribute to just `window.open()`, then it's okay. I tried using single quotes as well, but that also didn't work. So my guess is that it has to do with the quotations marks. How do I fix it?

```
$msg.html('<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-userName=' + msg.user +
' class="userName" onclick="window.open("https://www.google.com")">@'
+ msg.user + '</a>: ' + msg.message + ')');
```

Comment: Although the problem can be solved by escaping the nested quotes, I'll suggest to use jQuery's `.on()` to bind events.

Comment: Would it be possible to get a context of what exactly we're looking at? What's the HTML that goes with it?

Comment: @Tushar Could you explain how please?

Comment: You can bind the event using event delegation using `.on()` only once `// Execute this only once
$msg.on('click', 'a.userName', function () {
    window.open("https://www.google.com");
    return false;
});`

Then when adding anchor element
`// Anchor without href and onclick attribute
$msg.html('<a data-userName=' + msg.user +
    ' class="userName">@' + msg.user + '</a>: ' + msg.message + ')');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try escaping double quotes with \ (backslash)

```
$msg.html('<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-userName=' + msg.user +
' class="userName" onclick="window.open(\"https://www.google.com\")">@'
+ msg.user + '</a>: ' + msg.message + ')');
```